# how to find minimum difference object of collection in c# linq

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have collection

```
Class MyData
{
 int f1;
 int f2;
 int f3;
 int f4;
}

var mycollection =List<MyData>();
```

I need to return object with minimal difference between field `f1` and `f3`.

I tried below query

```
mycollection.select(obj => obj.f1 - obj.f3).Min();
```

But it will return the diff number. I need to return the object. 
I am kind of struggling to get the object with minimum difference

I also tried this

```
mycollection.Select(obj => new { MyObject = obj,
                diff = obj.MaxTemparature - obj.MinimumTemparature, obj
            }).Min(obj => obj.diff);
```

Comment: Whats the logic behind `f1 -f3`?

Comment: just create one field which is an int f1 - f3 i.e. calculated on constructor, it will be way easier

Answer (score 6):

Try this one

```
 MyData myData = mycollection.OrderBy(o => (o.f1 - o.f3)).First();
```

Comment: Hi @Ajith Nair, While this answer could resolve the OP's problem, You should add some more explanation to make it clearer. +1

Answer (score 3):

You can do below steps to find object by difference `F1 - F3`.

1. Calculate difference using `.Select()` and store it with actual object.
2. Sort it using `.OrderBy()` and use difference as a predicate.
3. Get First record from it.

   ```
   var result = myData.Select(x => new {diff = Math.Abs(x.F1 - x.F3), obj = x})  //Step 1
                .OrderBy(y => y.diff)   //Step 2
                .FirstOrDefault();     //Step 3
   ```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hx74nc)

---

Or you can perform subtraction without `.Select()`

```
    var result = myData.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x.F1 - x.F3)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like below.

```
 mycollection.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x.f1 - x.f3)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Order your collection by difference and you want `minimal difference` so used `Math.Abs(x.f1 - x.f3)`. Then take `FirstOrDefault` object.

[Test it here](https://rextester.com/REXLN83600)